# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Randbedingungen und Rahmenbedingungen?

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern *Randbedingungen* und *Rahmenbedingungen*? Sind diese synonym zu verwenden?

Kontext sind die Rahmen- oder Randbedingungen einer Hausarbeit wie zum Beispiel Schriftart oder Zeilenabstand. Eine allgemeine Antwort wäre aber optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die beiden Begriffe sollten nicht synonym verwendet werden.

Im genannten Kontext einer Hausarbeit stelllen Schriftart, Zeilenabstand, Seitenränder, usw. eine Rahmenbedingung dar, die bei Bedarf auch sehr speziell für einen Zweck vorgegeben wird. Die Vorgabe der Schriftgröße von mindestens 14pt für das Manuskript einer Ministerrede und ein vergrößerter Zeilenabstand sind Beispiele dafür.

Die **Rahmenbedingung** ist eine Bedingung, die für etwas den äußeren Rahmen absteckt, d.h. die von außerhalb des betrachteten Systems oder Vorgangs vorgegeben ist.

Beispiele siehe auch [Wortschatz: Rahmenbedingungen](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=Rahmenbedingungen) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rahmenbedingung)

Im genannten Kontext einer Hausarbeit stellen Quellenangaben eine (optionale) Randbedingung dar, die sich indirekt aus Zitierregeln ergeben und nicht explizit vorgegeben werden. Es können auch Regeln für Abbildungsverzeichnisse sein.

Die **Randbedingung** ist eine Bedingung, die bei etwas zu beachten ist.

Beispiele siehe auch [Wortschatz: Randbedingungen](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=Randbedingungen) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Randbedingung)